# Mongo Client seems to close automatically after a time and gives "state should be : open" exception

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo db and I'm trying to make it work with my java application using the java driver.

After the creation of the mongo client, my program then look for new users on the platform and makes Mongo register them one by one. Everything works fine until this point.

However when I run an update a protocol a bit later using the same Mongo client and on the cursor creation instruction, it throws the following exception :

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:287)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.cursor(MongoIterableImpl.java:97)
    at fr.wollfie.reward_bot.bot.io.mongo_db.MongoInvite.checkSponsorshipMaturation(MongoInvite.java:159)
    at fr.wollfie.reward_bot.bot.update.Looper.lambda$static$0(Looper.java:23)
    at fr.wollfie.reward_bot.bot.update.UpdatingProcess.update(UpdatingProcess.java:40)
    at fr.wollfie.reward_bot.bot.update.Looper.update(Looper.java:37)
    at fr.wollfie.reward_bot.bot.Bot.lambda$onGuildReady$1(Bot.java:131)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Here is the code I am using to connect Mongo and then where the exception is thrown

```java
public static void init() {
        mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:" + port);


        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

        for (Collection c : Collection.values()) {
            boolean exists = false;
            for (Document d : database.listCollections()) {
                if (d.get("name").equals(c.collectionName)) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }

            if (!exists) {
                database.createCollection(c.collectionName);
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
protected static MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(Collection c) {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME).getCollection(c.getCollectionName());
}

public static void checkSponsorshipMaturation(JDA jda) {
        MongoCollection<Document> sponsorships = MongoDB.getCollection(Collection.SPONSORSHIPS);

        try(MongoCursor<Document> c = sponsorships.find().cursor()) {
                                                        // Here
            while (c.hasNext()) {
                //stuff stuff
            }
        }
}
```

I am only closing the mongo client in the main, at the very end in a finally clause and nowhere else.

I don't know if it is relevant but I also tried to maxIdleTimeMS connection parameter to a big value and it didn't change anything.

To me the solution seems to be to use MongoClients.create() each time one of my eventHandlers or update processes get triggered but is there anything more convenient I could do ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's a link to a [FAQ post](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-mongodb-deployments-) on the [Connect to MongoDB](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) documentation page. Does that help with your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your link, the FAQ seems to mention only problems about the mongod service which I have none with since I am using a javascript application too which interacts with the same database with no problem. Now that I mention it I recall having issues with it too before I used `await client.connect()`before each mongo related instruction. I should do the same in my java application but since there is a lot of places I use such instructions, I really would like to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an error not knowing enough about Threads. I was originally closing the connection in the main, in a finally clause as I mentioned, thinking the other processes running would block the Thread but it appears that nothing was blocking the Main Thread from reaching the end and this finally clause.

So the connection was closed and the main stopped with the application still running. It was such a dumb mistake and I thank you for your comment and help.